# how to merge two tuple seq with specified key gracefully?

Tags: f#

I wrote the code but looks ugly.
Image there are two seqs like:

```
let x = [(1,"x");(2,"y")]
let y = [(1, "xx", "xxx");(2,"yy","yyy")]
```

The elements are tuples but not the same shape.
The result need to be `[(1, "x", "xx", "xxx");(2, "y", "yy", "yyy")]`.
The first element in the tuple is the key here.

The code I wrote used map like:

```
let x = [(1,"x");(2,"y")]
let y = [(1, "xx", "xxx");(2,"yy","yyy")]  
let mapY = y |> Seq.map (fun (a,b,c) -> (a, (b, c))) |> Map.ofSeq

let r = [
    for (k,v) in x do
        let (v1,v2) = mapY |> Map.tryFind k |> Option.orElse (Some ("","")) |> Option.get
        yield (k, v, v1, v2)
]

printfn "%A" r
```

not so gracefully.
So I wonder any better solution?(The tuple element in the question can be seq type, tuple just for example).
The key question is how to merge two seq by key gracefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using the `query` computation expression (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) for more info and examples). In your case, a solution would look like this:

```
let r =
    query {
        for (k1, v) in x do
        join (k2, v1, v2) in y on (k1 = k2)
        select(k1, v, v1, v2) }
    |> Seq.toList
```

Note that the `join` operator used here is in fact an inner join. There are a lot of other join-methods (as well as other operators) listed on the page linked to above.

Comment: @fairjm beware, by the way, that the parenthesis around `k1 = k2` are required!

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the use of `join` as shown by @torbonde is probably the nicest way to do this.

If you preferred to stick to basic `List` functions, then I think what you have is probably as good as it can be. One minor tweak would be to replace `orElse` with `defaultValue`:

```
let (v1,v2) = mapY |> Map.tryFind k |> Option.defaultValue ("","")
```

Another thing I'd consider is whether you need flat tuples - if you were happy with nesting of tuples on both the input and the output side, you could do something like this (which is essentially still your original code, but a bit shorter):

```
let x = [(1,"x");(2,"y")]
let y = [(1, ("xx", "xxx"));(2,("yy","yyy"))]  

let mapY = Map.ofSeq y
let r = x |> List.map (fun (k, v) -> 
     k, v, defaultArg (mapY.TryFind k) ("",""))
```